# No power options available after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, group-policy, power-options

About two weeks ago after a Windows 10 Professional update, several users with administrator privileges cannot shut down their computer from the Windows button.

If I log on as administrator I am able to shut down the computer from the Windows button. In an effort to fix it I have set the Group Policy: computer configuration - Policies - Windows Settings - Security Settings - Local Policies - User Rights Assignment - Shut down the system to everyone and still the problem exists. Has anyone had this issue and/of have a fix?

Trying to restart via PowerShell gives this:

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> restart-computer
 restart-computer : Failed to restart the computer 10-1-3-30 with the
 following error message: Privilege not held. .
 At line:1 char:1
 + restart-computer
```

Comment: Important: Are they in a AD?

Comment: Yes, all users are in the AD.

Comment: Please add this to your question. Afterwards, flag the comments as obsolete

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this link:

https://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/power-options-missing-after-windows-10-creators-update.html

> Many users found the power option missing in the start menu after
>   Windows 10 Creators Update. All the power options are not available in
>   Windows 10 CU when you clicking on the power option in the start menu,
>   you may no longer see the Sleep/Shut Down/Restart option. Instead,
>   you'll get a message, saying “There are currently no power options
>   available.” The only way to sleep/shutdown your computer is to log out
>   since the power options are available on the sign in the interface. To
>   get rid of the unsless Windows 10 power options and find those
>   features back, below are a few tricks for your reference.
>
> Read More:
>
> Fix Start Menu Not Working after Windows 10 Creators Update
>
> **Method 1.**
>
> **Run SFC /Scannow to Fix Power Options Missing Issue on Windows 10 Creators Update**
>
> The power option missing or not working error in Windows 10 Creators
>   Update could also be caused by corrupt or missing system files. To
>   rule out that possibility, you could run the SFC command (System File
>   Checker) to repair the problematic system files and retrieve the power
>   options. Below is how:
>
> 1. Press **Win + X** to select Command Prompt (Admin).
> 2. Type **sfc /scannow** and then hit Enter. (Make sure to put a space between   “sfc” and the slash.)
> 3. Type **powercfg –restoredefaultschemes** after the sfc /scannow command   completes and then hit Enter.
> 4. Type **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth** and hit **Enter**.
> 5. Reboot your computer after the process finishes and then try the Sleep, Shut down, or restart option in the power menu to check whether
>      the power options are available now.
>
> **Method 2.**
>
> **Tweak Group Policy Editor to Resolve Windows 10 No Power Options Available after Creators Update**
>
> If running the SFC commands fails to fix the futile power options in
>   Windows 10, try the Group Policy Editor tweak as below tutorials.
>   Before the registry tweak, you’d better backup your registry first in
>   case of any further system issues like blue screen, black screen with
>   cursor, Windows Hello not working etc.
>
> 1. Go to **Search**, type **gpedit.msc** to open **Group Policy Editor**.
> 2. Navigate to the following path:
>
> **User Configuration** -> **Administrative Templates** -> **Start Menu and Taskbar**
>
> 3. Double-click on "Remove and Prevent Access to the Shut Down command".
> 4. Select “Not Configured” or “Disabled” and then click **Apply**.
> 5. Close the Group Policy Editor and then try the power options menu to see if the sleep/hibernate/restart option functions now.
>
> **Pro Tip：**
>
> If you are a Windows 10 Home user, the Group Policy Editor is not
>   available. But you can run **regedit** to open the Registry Editor and
>   then follow the below path to find the missing power options back:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>
> Ensure that a value named NoClose exists with a value of 0.
>
> Reboot your computer and check whether the Power Options missing bug
>   gets fixed.
>
> **Method 3.**
>
> **Add User Rights in the Local Security Settings to Get the Missing Power Options Back**
>
> Add User Rights in the Local Security Policy is also said helpfully to
>   repair the power options malfunction:
>
> 1. Press **Win** + **R** keys and type: **secpol.msc** and then hit **Enter** to open the **Local Security Policy**.
> 2. Go to: **Security Settings** –> **Local Policies** –> **User Rights Assignment** –> Shut down the system.
> 3. Choose **Properties** and then **Add Users or Group** to add your user id or group.
>
> [power-options-not-available-windows-10-creators-update.jpg][4]
>
> 4. Once the new user or group has been added, click **OK** to save changes.
> 5. Sign out and Restart your computer.
> 6. Sign in and then you should find the Restart & Shutdown options are   available.
>
> **Method 4.**
>
> **Update Drivers for the Creators Update to Retrieve the Power Options in Start Menu**
>
> Incompatible drivers can result in issues like unresponsive power
>   options menu, **cursor disappearing**, **CHKDSK /F/R not working**,
>   **mouse lagging** etc. after Windows 10 CU. To update your device drivers to match the Windows 10 Creators Update and resolve the
>   glitchy power options from start menu via a time and energy saving
>   way, we recommend you to use a professional driver update and
>   management utility, like **Driver Talent**. Favored by millions of
>   people worldwide, Driver Talent detects your problematic drivers and
>   then fixes them by downloading the best-matched drivers for Windows
>   computer.
>
> Follow the steps to update drivers and troubleshoot the power options
>   no longer available problem on Windows 10 CU.
>
> **Step 1.**
>   **Scan for Problematic Drivers**
>
> Click “scan” and Driver Talent will scan for all the drivers installed
>   on Windows 10 Creators Update.
>
> **Step 2.**
>
> **Update the Best-matched Drivers**
>
> All the problematic drivers will show to you after step 1. Click
>   “Download” or “Update” to install the proper drivers and solve
>   unresponsive power options hitch for Windows 10.
>
> Notes: Backup your drivers in advance in case you want to roll back
>   drivers in the future.
>
> **Step 3.**
>
> **Reboot Your PC**
>
> Restart your Windows 10 Creators Update laptop or desktop PC to make
>   the updated driver take effect.
>
> Above are all troubleshooters we find to fix **Power Options Missing
>   after Windows** 10 Creators Update. If you know more solutions on the
>   unresponsive power options problem, please share with us in the
>   comment section below, or go to the **OStoto official forum** for
>   further discussion via the left menu on the page.

Comment: The link is not working. That link has nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: It is working fine.

Comment: Now it is working fine. It didn't before. Always remember to put the copied content in the block quotes. Otherwise it is plagiarism. You can visit [Formatting help](https://superuser.com/help/formatting) and [article about website promotion](https://superuser.com/help/promotion). Have a good day.

Comment: I found this about a week ago an none of the options worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. go to search bar, type services.msc then enter. then go to windows update. then right click that and just click the restart or stop button. Then go back to windows update and it should say there restart option. the computer will restart and install the updates. After rebooting the shutdown button should show up again like before.

Answer (score -1):

My solution for this problem was solved here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/there-are-currently-no-power-options-available/ed94a9da-e6b1-4a15-9710-a3da9be20395

You need to verify, if you have permissions for shutting down the computer.
It usually happens when computer is joined to domain.

start **secpol.msc**, go to Local Policies -> User Rights assignment -> Shutdown the system.
There you can see, who can shutdown the computer.